# Error while export of site in a unattached content database

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a content database to a sql server which is used by sharepoint 2010.

using the central administratoion I am able to browse the sites and export the sites.

But I worte a program to use the sharepoint APIs to do the same but I get the following error. i am filling the settings structure and calling export.run.

The url I am sending for the export

//vinay10:2434/sites/99156/test112/111

vinay10:2434 is the central admin webapp.

And using the central admin too it shows similar values --- //vinay10:2434/sites/99156 is the site collection

sites/99156/test112/111 is the site.

I attached the content database also before calling export.run. But I get the following error. Can any one tell me what I am missing

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: sites/99156/temp2/whatsup
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUnattachedDatabaseUtility.LookupIdContentDatabase(SPContentDatabase database, String serverRelativeUrl)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(SPContentDatabase contentDatabase, Uri requestUri, Boolean isHostHeader)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPExport.InitializeExport()

Answer (score 0):

SPExportSettings.UnattachedContentDatabase = "you unattached content DB"